# Maybe grandma put it away

Tags: grammar

Grandma put his toy away.

He woke up and looking for his toy.

"Where is my toy?" he asked.

> "Maybe grandma put it away."
>
> "Your toy has been putting away."

Do the used of put away correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Put away" has been used correctly in the first instance (you put something somewhere, it is the something, and away is where it was put)

The second instance is incorrect. Putting is the action ("I am putting away your toy now, as it is time for dinner.") whereas the historic action is "Put", so the correct quote block looks like this:

> Your toy has been put away.

(apologies for you English teachers out there - I honestly cannot remember the correct phrase for an action word in the past or present)

Comment: The term you're looking for is past participle: the passive is constructed from a form of *be* followed by the past participle. *Put* is an irregular verb, and its past participle and present and past forms are all identical: *put*.

Comment: To add to this, the phrase "putting away" would only be used in the present, that is, during the time when the toy is being put away. At that moment, the grandmother might say, "Grandma is putting your toy away."